# Chemical equilibrium of inorganic complexes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium

After mixing Cobalt(II) Chloride hexahydrate with ammonium chloride a violet complex forms, what would be the complex formed?
It was the precursor for producing hexamine cobalt chloride so I didn't characterize it.
I expect many compounds like hexaqua cobalt chloride and pentamine aqua cobalt chlride or amine chloro coblat complex?

Comment: The [ammine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexamminecobalt(III)_chloride) complexes of cobalt form in stages and have different colors. Which complex forms depends on the relative concentration of ammonia to the cobalt(II) ions as well as the pH.

Comment: Well thanks, amount of ammonia is approximately three times larger than that of cobalt, I think ammonium tetrachloro cobaltate (NH4)2[CoCl4] would form also but still not sure about it.